Crawl data by python using Fetch/XHR
I try to use python to crawl data from website
https://www.premierleague.com/clubs/1/Arsenal/squad?se=578

I can see raw in preview but cannot crawl data when go to link in name
https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/clubs/1
import requests
import pandas as pd


headers = {'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/clubs/1' 

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

df = pd.json_normalize(r.json())

print(df)

I try to get raw data which I can see in preview
